# Optimizing Dictionary.EnumerateFiles over network

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, optimization

I currently have a program that scans network shares. In order to do so, it first enumerates all the files and directories on the share. This is a very slow process. I currently use the below code, taken from a 2011 answer on this site.

```
static class SafeWalk
    {
        public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFiles(string path, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOpt)
        {
            try
            {
                var dirFiles = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
                if (searchOpt == SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                {
                    dirFiles = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path)
                                        .SelectMany(x => EnumerateFiles(x, searchPattern, searchOpt));
                }
                return dirFiles.Concat(Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, searchPattern));
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that everything else in the program is multi-threaded and optimized for speed. This is the only area that is seriously holding me back. It can takes a score of minutes to enumerate the files in the network share. This is on an intranet, and there are gigabit connections or greater between my machine and the server.

I did speed it up a good bit when I mapped the network path to a drive temporarily at runtime. Is there anything I can do to make this go faster? Looking at the resource monitor, it is barely using any CPU, memory or network bandwidth.

Comment: Instead of creating a recursive method, wouldn't it be easier to just use the appropriate overload for [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Directory.EnumerateFiles throws an error if you don't have access to a file/directory. If it does so, it only returns what it discovered so far which could be 3MB out of 70GB. :-(

Comment: Then I guess your only option is the fast directory enumerator linked below. Repeatedly catching exceptions and recursive method in C# will be slower than straight enumeration though...

Comment: What kind of access you have to this network share? Can you remote and run code on that box? Or is it just plain vanilla network share with limited permission to only read and write files?

Comment: @VikasGupta I have no access to run the code on the server. I have read/write access to about 98% of the files contained on the share. Certain directories are off-limits, even to me.

Comment: Ok.. so the possibility of running code remotely is out.. At this point I can only suggest improvements like, if Parent directory has 10 child directories.. then instead of enumerating those 10 one by one, you could add some degree of parallelism.. The tricky part will be to limit the parallelism for directories which are very deep. It does have good potential for improving the enumeration time.. but be careful not to overload your thread pool.. I also check if there is an async version of these API, which would have immensely helped. but I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using PInvoke to call [`FindFirstFileEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364419(v=vs.85).aspx) with the option `FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH`. [According to Raymond Chen this flag is made for your situation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/10/24/10459773.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately, that value is not valid for Windows 7.

Comment: @Red_Shadow in that case I recommend that you write a small app that runs on the remote machine and that exposes an API to enumerate directories. You can then use fast local enumeration and efficiently stream the results over the network in a non-chatty way.

Comment: Actually, rereading the msdn, I think it says that it is supported in Windows 7 and up, it's just worded awkwardly. Also, I cannot execute any code at all on the remote machines. The tool is meant to be housed on a scanning machine and be able to scan any other machine on the network.

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching the same path with the same search parameter often under a high volume? Are you ok with using cached results? If so, I recommend adding in a caching mechanism. We've run into something similar, although we weren't exposing it quite so generically and granular, and I just cached the results. Or if you're not comfortable with that, is it possible that the caller's logic is not saving the results and is looping over multiple calls to this?

Answer (score -2):

[Fast Directory Enumerator](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38959/A-Faster-Directory-Enumerator)
is the thing for you.

Why is it Faster?

Directory.GetFiles and DirectoryInfo.GetFiles or Directory.EnumerateFile() have a number of disadvantages. The most significant is that they throw away information and do not efficiently allow you to retrieve information about multiple files at the same time.

Internally, Directory.GetFiles is implemented as a wrapper over the Win32 FindFirstFile/FindNextFile functions. These functions all return information about each file that is enumerated that the GetFiles() method throws away when it returns the file names. They also retrieve information about multiple files with a single network message.

The FastDirectoryEnumerator keeps this information and returns it in the FileData class. This substantially reduces the number of network round-trips needed to accomplish the same task.

Comment: No, that project pre-dates the addition of the EnumerateFiles/Directory() methods in .NET 4.0.  Which solve the exact same problem.  The OP is already using it.

Comment: Attempted to use this library: It's about 5x slower in initial testing that my current solution.

Comment: Last time I looked using Reflector the info from FindFirstFile is not being thrown away.

Comment: Please don't lead people to use that. The `Directory.EnumerateFiles/Directory` methods are already in .NET and better.